# Request notification permission through powershell

Tags: powershell

I have this piece of code:

```
[Windows.UI.Notifications.Management.UserNotificationListener, Windows.UI.Notifications, ContentType = WindowsRuntime]
 $listener = [Windows.UI.Notifications.Management.UserNotificationListener]::Current
 $accessStatus = $listener.GetAccessStatus()

 switch($accessStatus)
 {
   "Allowed" {
     Write-host "Yay! Proceed as normal"
   }
   "Denied" {
     Write-host"Access denied"
   }
   "Unspecified" {
     Write-host "Do something, idk"
   }
 }
```

that is supposed to request notification permission for an app.
So, I call the script through the app and it always returns "Yay! Proceed as normal" even when I disable access manually from the settings. Is this because it's requesting permission as powershell and not as my app because I call the script from the app, or am I doing something else wrong here?
[Notification listener: Access all notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/notification-listener)

Comment: how is it calling the target application? The .GetAccessStatus() method from the listener doesn't appear to be listening to anything, unless ::Current means the current app context I'm guessing

Comment: Well, that's what I don't understand.... is it a syntax error? What should the correct way be to ask permission for the app that's running the powershell script?